# XSD assertions conditioned by the existence of attributes

Tags: xml, testing, xsd, assert

I am looking for a solution to the following case:

Suppose that you have 2 attributes in an XSD 1.1: "startDate" and "endDate".
Suppose also that those are optional and you need to check if those are present or not. The following xsd shall work:

```
<complexType name="exampleType">
    <attribute name="startDate" type="date" use="optional" />
    <attribute name="endDate" type="date" use="optional" />
    <assert test="(exists(@startDate) = exists(@endDate))"/>
</complexType>
```

What I would need is a way check that startDate is less or equal to endDate only in case both of them are provided. I have tried with those asserts:

```
<assert test="(exists(@startDate) = exists(@endDate)) and (@startDate le @endDate)"/>

<assert test="exists(@startDate) = (@startDate le @endDate)" />
```

But it does not work, when none of the attributes exist it provides a false because tries to execute the comparison.

Is it possible to check that both attributes exist before apply a comparison with Test?
It would be very interesting to have the possibility to test something conditioned by a previous test.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<assert test="not(@endDate lt @startDate)"/>
```

Comment: Alternative which solves also the problem:

    <assert test="if (exists(@startDate) and exists(@endDate)) then (@startDate le @endDate) else true()" />